# Drawing a square in canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

I have a canvas that is drawing a circle with predefined bounds.

```
canvas.drawCircle((float) (getBounds().right / 2), (float) (getBounds().bottom / 2), (float) (getBounds().right / 2), paint);
```

and now I need to make it draw a square instead of a circle. so this is what I modified

`(getBounds().right / 2)` instead of it dividing by `2` I didn't divide it by anything for the radius

how ever it just overflows.

So this is how it looks like when its a normal circle.

[image]

and this is how it looks when I attempted to make it a square

[image]

can someone please suggest me how I can draw a successful square with the bounds I have been given?

Comment: Maybe use `drawRectangle()` instead of `drawCircle()`?

Comment: It's `drawRect()`, sorry. And a square is, by definition, a rectangle. It's just a special type, with equal sides.

Comment: Yes, you need to adjust it. You can't expect calling `drawCircle()` to draw a square.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26263753 You may find this useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look's like the answer was fairly simple.

all I had to do is pass my `rect` and `paint` to `Canvas::drawRect`

here is the code

```
Rect rect = drawable.getBounds();
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

and image of the result

[image]